# How to remove parentheses from xml string in iOS?

Tags: ios

Here is string
<FirstName>Anand</FirstName><br/> <MiddleName>Kumar</MiddleName><br/> <LasttName>Mangal</LasttName><br/>

How to get First Name---Anand, Middle Name---Kumar, Last Name---Mangal

Comment: you probably will need to parse that xml. What have you tried ?

Comment: I parsed web service and i am getting above data in response.So my Question is how to extract first name,last name & middle name from above httpResponse.

Comment: That doesn't change what I said, XML is a data format that as far as I know you can't use that way. You need to parse it to a comprehensible data format for iOS.

Comment: i used SOAP UI for that.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [XMLParser](https://github.com/Zedenem/XMLParser) or [SHXMLParser](https://github.com/simhanature/SHXMLParser)